# Vector Erase Error

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
int main ()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int noOfElements = 9;
    for (int a = 0; a < 9; a++)
    {
        std::vector<int> poss;
        for (int a = 1; a <= 9; a++)
            poss.push_back(a);
        for (int b = 0; b < 9; b++)
        {
            int random = rand() % 9;
            std::cout << poss[random];
            poss.erase(random);
            noOfElements--;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Yet when I run it, it returns this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::erase(int&)'
```

for line 13.

Why is this and how can I correct it?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase

Comment: Are you trying to erase a random position, or a random value? It makes quite a big difference.

Comment: This would be a lot shorter and more robust if you used standard algorithms. `std::iota` replaces your first inner loop, and `std::random_shuffle` shuffles them. `std::copy` can output them, and `std::vector::clear` can reset the vector.

Comment: Once `erase` starts working, you'll need to change `rand() % 9` to `rand() % noOfElements`.

Comment: I hadn't come across `std::iota`. Neat. I've yet to find a full, complete and easy-to-read list of everything new in C++11...

Answer (score 13):

You cannot erase *values* from a vector directly (vectors are sequence containers, not associative containers): you need to provide an iterator to the element that you want to be erased.

In order to get an iterator, you may either:

- find the element based on its value (e.g. by using [`std::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)) and then provide the returned iterator in input to the [`erase()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) member function, or
- get it by applying an offset to the iterator which points to the beginning of your vector (i.e. the object returned by the [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin) member function).

**In the first case**:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2, 3};
    auto i = std::find(begin(v), end(v), 2);
    v.erase(i);
}
```

The above code uses some C++11 features. In C++03, it would look as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;

    v.push_back(1);
    v.push_back(2);
    v.push_back(3);

    std::vector<int>::iterator i = std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 2);
    v.erase(i);
}
```

**In the second case**, if you know the *index* of your element inside the vector (say, `pos`), then you can easily get an iterator this way:

```
v.begin() + pos
```

Alternatively (C++11 only) you could do:

```
next(begin(v), pos);
```

Comment: In this case, I think he'd most likely want `std::vector<int>::iterator it = poss.begin() + random; std::cout << *it; poss.erase(it);`

Comment: @Chowlett: Re-reading the question, it seems you are right. Initially I thought `random` was the *value* the OP wanted to erase, not its position. But that's probably not the case, so I updated my answer to cover both situations. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

you have to pass an iterator to erase. So try

```
poss.erase(poss.begin() + random);
```

Comment: I think this is a the correct answer, but Andy Prowl could be right instead.

Comment: @john yes, I agree, I was going to edit my post to say that I wasn't sure what the OP's intention is. I also have a concern that the OP's loop is going to go past the end of the array -- I'd want to analyse the logic a bit more to convince myself that it's ok (or maybe just add something to check, e.g. on the lines of `assert(random < poss.size())`

Answer (score 0):

Vector erase function takes iterator not value.
And also you need to check for boundary condition to see the index you are erasing is not out of bound.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator itr = poss.begin() + random;
if(itr != poss.end())
{
  poss.erase(itr);
}
```

Comment: The bounds check you're doing is woefully inadequate.  It checks the iterator against one possible invalid value.  Of course, it would be undefined behavior to form any iterator farther out of bounds than that.  So, if you really want to do a bounds check, you should do it on the integer, before you add it to `poss.begin()`.  Of course, if you're in complete control of the generation of the integer, as is the case here, that's where the value of the integer should be bound: `int random = rand() % poss.size();`.  Any additional checks are redundant.