# Remove element from vector error C++

Tags: c++, vector, element

I know this might seem as a duplicate question, but it is not, I have a problem with a function and don''t know why it behaves like that.

I have a vector which holds elements of type MyMaterial** (std::vector). At a point in my program, I will know an element, "currentElement", and I will want to remove it.

I tried doing this:

```
myMaterials.erase(currentElement);
```

But here is the problem: Instead of only deleting "currentElement", it also deletes all elements added after it. Why does it do that and how can I solve it?

I must mention that I don''t know the position of "currentElement" in the vector, and i prefere not to search for it, I''m hoping there is another way.

Comment: What type is the currentElement?
If you have the index you can use myMaterials.begin()+index
You need to use the iterator to do those type of operations

Comment: doesn't `vector::erase(n)` remove the n-th element? so if you have a element of type MyMaterial, you will have to find out at which position it is in the vector at first ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between erase and remove](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799314/difference-between-erase-and-remove)

Comment: possible duplicate of / see [Vector Erase Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16219027/vector-erase-error)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using std::vector, then:

> Erase elements Removes from the vector either a single element
>   (position) or a range of elements ([first,last)).

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

[How do I remove an item from a stl vector with a certain value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39912/how-do-i-remove-an-item-from-a-stl-vector-with-a-certain-value)

Answer (score 0):

To use `vector::erase(iterator)` to remove an element from a vector, you may either have to know its index OR iterate thru the list to hunt for it.

Luckily, There is the std::map, and this is how you would work it

```
std::map<std::string,myMaterial> myMaterials;
myMaterial mat;//assuming it doesnt take any args
myMaterials['myMaterialXYZ'] = mat; ///add it to the array
myMaterials.erase('myMaterialXYZ'); ///Erase by key..(or "name" in this case)
```

Now you can easily track string names instead of ever changing index positions...and memory locations, which by the way may be another ace up your sleeve.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn''t really use the examples given by you above, because I got all kinds of errors, due to the type of elements the vector holds. But I made a function which managed to delete the specific element:

```
int i=0;
int found=0;

MyMaterial **material = gMaterials.begin();
while(material != gMaterials.end() && found == 0)
{
  if(currentElement == material)
  {
    gMaterials.erase(gMaterials.begin() + i, gMaterials.begin() + i+1);
    found = 1;
  }
  i++;
  cloth++;
}
```

I don''t know how good/correct it is, but it does the job.

Thank you very much for the suggestions and the help.